# WordPress relative positioning and page height CSS issue

Tags: css, wordpress

I am using `position:relative` and `top:-120px` to move the header background image underneath the two header `<div/>`s, which works nicely. I then had to set the wrapper `<div/>` and footer `<div/>` to also be relative and move them both up 120 pixels to line up correctly. The problem is that the bottom of the page now has 120 pixels of extra space underneath the footer. Is there an easy way to remove that space? Or perhaps is there a different way of using CSS and the `position` property to achieve this result? Here's my site:

http://ledvideowall.net

Answer (score 1):

Here's the fix:

```
.wrapper {
    top: 0;
}
.site-header {
    margin-bottom: -120px;
}    
footer[role="contentinfo"]{
    top:0;
}
```

Comment: That doesn't work.  It just moves the footer down to the bottom, but then there is 120 pixels of space below the wrapper div and above the footer.  That was no accident - I said that I modified the css to move everything up in my question.

Comment: nice!  Yes, that is a simple solution.  :)

Answer (score 1):

I was going to say that `#headerbg` doesn't need to exist, but I see that you are using the image to maintain the height/width ratio of the header as the page sizes down.
When I need to do something like this, I don't position the "`background-image`" in this case at all, but make the wrapper `position:relative` and the `#headertop` & `#menubar` `position:absolute`. This takes the top and menu out of the flow and makes the `background image` the work.

```
.site-header {
  position:relative;
  ...
}
#headertop {
 position:absolute;
 top:0;
 left:0;
 width:100%;
 z-index:1;
...
}
#menubar {
 position:absolute;
 top:80px;
 left:0;
 width:100%;
 z-index:1;
 ...
}
#headerbg {
 display:block;
 height:auto;
 width:100%;
 /*
 position: relative;
 top: -120px;
 z-index: 0;
 */
}
#headerbg img {
 display:block;
 width:100%;
 height:auto;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for an alternate approach.  I will give that a shot here in the next few days and see if I can get it to work like that.

Answer (score 0):

You could apply `margin-bottom` to revert the effect the relative position causes:

```
footer[role="contentinfo"]{
    margin-bottom: -120px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you've intentionally moved the footer up 120px, you can do this to remove the white space below it.

```
footer[role="contentinfo"] {
    margin-bottom: -120px;
}
```